# simple alert box doesn't close after the first click, what to do to make it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

i have a simple jquery script that calls a fancybox after a button was clicked, 
now the problem is, the fancy box doesn't close after the first click of the button, only after the 2nd click...

The second problem is, inside the fancy box, there is a form with 3 input fields, the submit button/button doesn't work in one click, it needs to get clicked twice as well..any ideas on what to do?

```
jQuery("#hsbcloanbutton").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var loanAmount = jQuery('#loanAmount').val();
    var loanTenure = jQuery('#loanTenure').val();
    var InstalmentAmount = jQuery('#InstalmentAmount').val();
    var loanName = jQuery('#loanName').val();
    var loanNric = jQuery('#loanNric').val();
    var loanContact = jQuery('#loanContact').val();
    if(loanAmount.length < 1 || loanTenure.length  < 1 || InstalmentAmount.length < 1)
    {
        alert("Please enter data");
        return false;
    } else if(isNaN(loanAmount) || isNaN(InstalmentAmount)){
        alert("Please put numbers only in Loan Amount and Instalment Amount fields");
        return false;
    } else {
                jQuery("#hsbcloanbutton").fancybox({
                'titlePosition' : 'inside',
                'transitionIn' : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none',
                'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
                'hideOnContentClick' : false,
                'showCloseButton' : false,
        });


    }
    jQuery("#hsbcloansubmitformbutton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            'type' : 'POST',
            'url' : "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl?>",   
        )};
    });
});
```

Comment: @Starx The problems are likely related. It makes sense to merge them into one.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995, Agreed.

Comment: see console.log() to see which part of the `if/else` condition you are hitting.

Comment: hard to debug, @Starx, are you referring to the console tab of the firebug ?

Comment: add breakpoints in the script or lines like `console.log('if entered');` among your script lines.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are initializing your fancybox, on the click event: That might be causing this.

Initialize the script on `$(document).ready()`

```
$(function() {
        jQuery("#hsbcloanbutton").fancybox({
                'titlePosition' : 'inside',
                'transitionIn' : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none',
                'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
                'hideOnContentClick' : false,
                'showCloseButton' : false,
        });
});
```

Comment: if am gonna do this, the validation pops-up together with the fancy box